# Uniqueness of the decomposition of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $ F $ be a non-empty subset of $ \{ 1,2,\dots,n\} $ and $ P_{F}=(\{x_{i}:i\in F\}) $. Let $ F_{1},F_{2},\dots,F_{m} $ be pair-wise distinct non-empty subsets of $ \{1,2,...,n\} $ and
>   $$ I=\prod_{i=1}^{m}P_{F_{i}}^{a_{i}}$$
>   for some integers $ a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{k}\geq 1 $. Prove that $ I $ can be written uniquely in such a way.

My attempt: I know that the ideals $ P_{F_{i}} $ are prime ideals of $ k[x_{1},...,x_{n}] $ and that $ I $ admits a primary decomposition $ I=\cap_{j=1}^{r}Q_{j} $ where the $ Q_{j}$'s are primary ideals, but the $ P_{F_{i}}^{a_{i}}$'s are not comaximal so I can not use this to write $I$ as their intersection and somehow relate this to the primary decomposition. More than this, I don't know how to proceed.

I would really appreciate any ideas, hints or solutions. Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "written uniquely *in such a way*"? If change $m$ to $m'$, the subsets $F_i$ with some other subsets $F_i'$ and $a_i$ with some $a_i'$ then $k=k'$, $F_i=F_i'$ and $a_i=a_i'$ (eventually after renumbering)? (Btw, I've changes your $k$ by $m$ since $k$ denotes a field later on.)

Comment: Yes, exactly like you said, user26857. I am sorry that I was not clear about this. I should have definitely specified it.